# Input an Image from the Content/Files Folder on the storefront using Liquid (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, png, liquid, storefront

I am a complete beginner to Shopify's Liquid coding language.

I have an image in the Content/Files folder in the Admin named: 'free-returns-grey-box'.
It's a PNG file.

I have looked at the liquid docs but still can't seem to find a way to put this image on the storefront.

I am slowly loosing my patience but since this image is important for me, i don't want to give up.

Any ideas would be more than welcome.